# How do I install freedraw for leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

**I need to get a leaflet freedraw plugin to work with my project.** **But I have no idea how to do that because there is no real tutorial about how to do it on the entire internet it seems. What are the steps to get the plugin to work with the project?** I've visited the project's GitHub page but there is no tutorial either. **What I need to do before I can just sit and write the code?** I'm honestly trying to fix this for like two days but **there's just nothing to start from including old questions from Stack Overflow with zero answers...**

I've tried to install the plugin with ndm which gave me a bunch of errors with no results. Even after that, **I had no idea how to connect the plugin with my project or what to do...** I also tried installing the freedraw plugin with Bower which installed some files, **but still, I had no idea how to get them to work with my project.**

Leaflet freedraw plugin - https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw

Someone, please help I'm definitely not the first one waiting for full working step by step tutorial on how to get it running with leaflet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use npm or bower you can load the plugin directly like this

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.freedraw/2.0.1/leaflet-freedraw.web.js"></script>`

Invocation is as per the GitHub page

```
const freeDraw = new FreeDraw({ mode: FreeDraw.ALL });
map.addLayer(freeDraw);
```

Add options as required.